# How Can I detect a Network flows from captured packets?

Tags: python, scapy

I have to detect the Network Flow (ARP and IP) from my local NIC and extract some features like flow duration, Number of Bytes, etc based on the 5 basic parameters of a flow(source IP, destination IP, Protocol, and source and destination ports) to convert it to a .csv dataset using python.

I managed to see every packet with scapy and get those five basic parameters for each packet. However, I do not want packets I want flows. So, Do I have to look for pairs with reversed IP, Port numbers in destination and source? If yes, I do not know how to write a code to do that in a 5-minute live capture of the network.

Can anyone help?
This is my Code for extracting parameters.

```
def get_packet_layers(pkt):
    """Saves the layers of the flow (e.g. Ether/IP/TCP)"""
    yield pkt.name
    while pkt.payload:                     
        pkt = pkt.payload
        yield pkt.name

def extract_labels(pkt):
    """  Returns a dictionary containing those five labels extracted from each flow """
    layers= list(get_packet_layers(pkt))

    if layers[1] == 'ARP':                                      
        src_ip = pkt[0].getlayer(layers[1]).psrc                
        pkt_protocol = layers[1]                                
        src_port, dst_port = None                              
    else: 
        src_ip = pkt[0].getlayer(layers[1]).src                            
        dst_ip = pkt[0].getlayer(layers[1]).dst
        pkt_protocol = layers[2]
        src_port = pkt[0].getlayer(layers[2]).sport 
        dst_port = pkt[0].getlayer(layers[2]).dport
     
    flow_parameters = {'Source_IP': src_ip, 'Source_Port': src_port,
                'Destination_IP': dst_ip, 'Destination_Port': dst_port,'Protocol' :str(pkt_protocol)}
    return flow_parameters

def main():
    packets = sniff(iface="Wi-Fi", count=1000)
    for pkt in packets:  
        print(extract_labels(pkt))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, can you clarify a couple of points? You say you're using 5-tuple to to detect a flow - have you made any consideration to flows duration, and how you'll determine when a flow ends? When you say 'Network flow', are you just referring to raw packets, or Netflow v9/10?

Comment: What I mean by flow is a sequence of 5-tuple packets between two hosts. I am actually new to such concepts so I do not know what can be considered the 'end' or the 'start' of a flow (I guess the SYN and FIN flags can do that but I do not know how to implement that).

Comment: Are you looking to implement this for UDP as well? These don't have flags. Some TCP flows might never finish or you might receive a RST flag instead of FIN. Something to consider is a timeout.

Comment: So you mean it is quite impossible to extract those features from a flow? I mean what is your suggestion cause I do not know what to do.

Comment: No, not impossible. You need to make some assumptions about what it is you want to do in certain scenarios. Maybe consider the following, this list isn't exhaustive. 
Scenario 1: SYN -> FIN;
Scenario 2: SYN -> RST;
Scenario 3: SYN -> Flow timeout;
Scenario 4: UDP -> Flow timeout; 
Scenario 5: Long flow -> Interim updates??